# workflow or EventListener

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepointdocumentlibrary, eventreceiver, documentlistener

We are building an extranet sharepoint portal for our clients. Each client will have a site. Total number of sites will be between 2000-3000.

I have a requirement to copy a document from a SiteCollectionA/SiteA/DocumentLibrary to another global list on another site collection when a client uploads new document.

Should i create workflow to copy the document or event listener? Client will be allowed to update document properties after the upload and these changes will have to be pushed into the global list as well.

My choice would be event listener because is much cleaner, cheaper and easier. Im not an expert with workflows, but i think it will be harder to maintain/update/re-publish workflows on 2000+ sites then an event listener.

What do you guys think?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely an event receiver, all you are doing is a simple mechanical action in response to an event.
Event receivers are much easier to develop, deploy and maintain.

Comment: To add to this I honestly will say I probably won't do another "Workflow" ever again. I'll tell those I'm developing it for that yes they are getting a workflow but in truth its just a state machine. I've had too many issues with Workflows and SharePoint that adding the extra effort put in the proper state management is well worth it versus the troubleshooting I would have to do when implementing a workflow. 

One of many examples of this I have run into: 
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/9373f60f-9e60-43f5-9d6b-ae0c8cc8d089

Comment: i really dont have any experience with workflows. it makes me kinda nervous, because we are creaing maybe the most important system to interface with our clients.

Comment: If you just need "do x when y happens", go with an event receiver, much simpler and fool-proof, not to mention deployment and debugging